# Overloading operator<<(ostream&, T) where T is "enum class MyEnum"

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, ostream

I've been trying to overload operator<< so that I can do this with my enum types:

```
/* enum class Color { ... } */
Color color = GetColor();
std::wcout << L"The color is " << color << std::endl;
```

OUTPUT:

```
The color is Green.
```

Here's some test code I'm compiling in Visual Studio 2013:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

/* (global scope) */
enum class enum_type_1 { e1_enumerand };

inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, enum_type_1 value)
{
    return os << L"e1_enumerand"; // switch-cases omitted
}

class cls
{
public:
    enum class enum_type_2 { e2_enumerand };

    friend inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, enum_type_2 value)
    {
        return os << L"e2_enumerand"; // switch-cases omitted
    }
};

namespace ns
{
    enum class enum_type_3 { e3_enumerand };

    inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, enum_type_3 value)
    {
        return os << L"e3_enumerand"; // switch-cases omitted
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    enum_type_1      e1 = enum_type_1::e1_enumerand;
    cls::enum_type_2 e2 = cls::enum_type_2::e2_enumerand;
    ns::enum_type_3  e3 = ns::enum_type_3::e3_enumerand;

    std::wcout << L"The value of e1 is " << e1 << std::endl;
    std::wcout << L"The value of e2 is " << e2 << std::endl;
    std::wcout << L"The value of e3 is " << e3 << std::endl;

    std::cin.ignore();

    return 0;
}
```

If I replace "enum class" in the definitions with "class", this will compile, but the output is the integer values of the enumerands, so my overload isn't being found.

If I leave "enum class" in (I prefer type-safe enums), this fails to compile at all with the following error:

```
d:\...\main.cpp(43): error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'enum_type_1' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

(more error detail at bottom of post)

I've been Googling, reading, and trying all kinds of permutations, and I simply cannot get this to work. Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

---

Here's the detail on the error messages I'm getting. Notice that the compiler is finding my overloads via ADL, but not considering them a match. The signatures look identical to me... WTF?

```
d:\...\main.cpp(43): error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'enum_type_1' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
          c:\...\ostream(498): could be 'std::basic_ostream<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>> &std::basic_ostream<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>>::operator <<(std::basic_streambuf<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>> *)'
          .
          .
          .
          d:\...\main.cpp(11): or       'std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &,enum_type_1)'
          .
          .
          .
          with
          [
              _Ty=enum_type_1
          ]
          while trying to match the argument list '(std::basic_ostream<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>>, enum_type_1)'

d:\...\main.cpp(44): error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'cls::enum_type_2' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
          c:\...\ostream(498): could be 'std::basic_ostream<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>> &std::basic_ostream<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>>::operator <<(std::basic_streambuf<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>> *)'
          .
          .
          .
          d:\...\main.cpp(11): or       'std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &,enum_type_1)'
          d:\...\main.cpp(21): or       'std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &,cls::enum_type_2)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
          .
          .
          .
          c:\...\ostream(988): or       'std::basic_ostream<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>> &std::operator <<<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,cls::enum_type_2>(std::basic_ostream<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>> &&,const _Ty &)'
          with
          [
              _Ty=cls::enum_type_2
          ]
          while trying to match the argument list '(std::basic_ostream<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>>, cls::enum_type_2)'

d:\...\main.cpp(45): error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'ns::enum_type_3' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
          c:\...\ostream(498): could be 'std::basic_ostream<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>> &std::basic_ostream<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>>::operator <<(std::basic_streambuf<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>> *)'
          .
          .
          .
          d:\...\main.cpp(11): or       'std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &,enum_type_1)'
          d:\...\main.cpp(31): or       'std::ostream &ns::operator <<(std::ostream &,ns::enum_type_3)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
          .
          .
          .
          c:\...\ostream(988): or       'std::basic_ostream<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>> &std::operator <<<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,ns::enum_type_3>(std::basic_ostream<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>> &&,const _Ty &)'
          with
          [
              _Ty=ns::enum_type_3
          ]
          while trying to match the argument list '(std::basic_ostream<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>>, ns::enum_type_3)'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::ostream` is an alias for `std::basic_ostream<char>`.

`std::wcout` is of type `std::basic_ostream<wchar_t>`, also known as `std::wostream`. Note the different character types.

If you want your `operator<<` to work with `std::wcout`, it should take and return `std::wostream&` rather than `std::ostream&`.

Comment: Aargh. I looked at ostream and can swear I saw it was std::basic_ostream<wchar_t>